# How can a unified confidence score be achieved using multiple reviews?

Tags: probability, error-propagation

For a product `P1`, there are multiple reviewers: `R1, ..., Rn` (with corresponding reviewer Quality of `Q1, ..., Qn`). How should I mathematically combine the Scores (`S1, ..., Sn`) provided by all the Reviewers to come up with a final quality score?

*Note*: Reviewer ratings and Quality 
What I have so far:
`Final Quality Score = Sum(Qi * Si)/n`

Is this correct? Are there other approaches to doing this?

It appears to me that Ensemble learning is the way to go for such a problem. I don't know how it works exactly, so, if anyone has better alternatives, please recommend.

Comment: You should at least normalize by the sum of the quality $$S = \frac{\sum_i Q_i S_i}{\sum_i Q_i}$$ This is the weighted average of the $S_i$, with "higher-quality" reviewers getting higher weight in the final score.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you@AlexR

Comment: Here's the problem though. if Q1 and Q2 are 100%, and if S1 and S2 are 80% and 90% respectively, according to the formula, S = 85%. But intuitively, it feels like it should be higher than 80% or 90% because two independent people with the best reputation are saying that the product is great. No?

Comment: That's a philosophical question. I wouldn't consider reviews independent though, since they are supposed to somehow objectively measure the goodness of a product. If they were not, you'd need to make sure every reviewer has completely distinct preferences (in a sense opposite).